# Vim generate ascending numbers in visual mode

Tags: vim

When edit markdown list with Vim, I usually got what i think i want like this first:

```
1. item
2. item
3. item
4. item
```

but then realize that i forget something in the middle, so i insert one line in the middle, so the file become this

```
1. item
2. item added
2. item
3. item
4. item
```

I know that in markdown the list number do not have to be ordered, but i think it not easy to read, so i want to change the list number to be in ascending order like this.

```
1. item
2. item added
3. item
4. item
5. item
```

I know that i can use this command for that:

```
let i=1 | g/\d. /s//\=i.'. '/ | let i=i+1
```

But it will change all list number in the markdown file, how can i run this command in visual mode of Vim.

Comment: after some search i find i can use range for `g` command, so i can use the follow command for my job: `let i=1 | '<,'> g/\d. /s//\=i.'. '/ | let i=i+1` Is there any better method for this job?

Comment: FWIW, Markdown parsers don't care about the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion:

https://github.com/triglav/vim-visual-increment

Why? It allows you to perform the same kind of task easily.

Comment: it wouldn't help if there are other non empty  lines between two items